# ERROR: Index was out of range: if (formula2MatrixResult[i][j] < 0), 2D List<> in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am getting an error saying the index is out of bound and I suspect it has to do with a mistake in Formula2 method. The formuala2Matrix(formula2 method) is supposed to be a 20 columns by 5 row matrix and I am not sure if thats what I created in Formula2 method. If yes, then I got get why I have an error in formula3 method. Thank you for ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Formula2`, the `k` has been added to `k+2`

1. `k++` in the `for` loop
2. `k++` in `if (k == j)`

```
for (int k = 0; k < Alternatives_Count; k++)
{
    if (k == j)
        k++;
    else
        formula2.Add(formula1MatrixResult[i][j] - formula1MatrixResult[i][k]);
}
```

if you want to add only once, you can write like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < Alternatives_Count; k++)
{
    if (k != j)
    {
        formula2.Add(formula1MatrixResult[i][j] - formula1MatrixResult[i][k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! that helped